# Play!: Use different version of jar than local repository

Tags: jar, playframework, classloader

Play! framework comes with tons of jar libraries. I am using version 1.7 of apache commons-codec for my Play! application. But Play! is already shipped with version 1.4 and some other older versions. I have placed my commons-codec-1.7.jar in the lib folder, and 'eclipsified' so the jar file is in the class path. But when I expand the Project Explorer in Eclipse I see that both version 1.7 and 1.4 are referenced by the application. My questions are

1. How do I remove version 1.4 from being referenced?
2. Why did the app choose version 1.4 even though version 1.3 and 1.2 are present in the [PLAY_HOME]/repository/local
3. It is a collaborative project. I want to make sure that once I push the code in git and my colleagues pull it, they need not to do the same 'hack', just 'clean' and 'compile'. How can it be done?

BTW, I am using Play! 2.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `commons-codec` to your `Build.scala` and you'll be fine. The dependencies will be correct since the specified dependency will override the ones that are default.

```scala
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.7"
)
```

1. You don't have to *remove* version 1.4. Version 1.7 will be in effect now.
2. That is caused by the order they are presented in the classpath.
3. `play compile` will do it. And you'll have to eclipsify the project again.

Don't forget to remove the `commons-codec` from the `lib` folder. As said it will be downloaded and put in the classpath automatically.

Comment: Thanks. May be this is the best solution. But is there a way to avoid compile time download? I mean, if I keep the file in **lib** directory and *eclipsify*, users will get the jar file from the project, right? In that way they will be able to share (may be via thumb-drive) and run the project without worrying about internet connection.

Comment: @khalid If you do it this way you know that you get all the transitive dependencies as well. Personally I don't like to add binary files to the VCS (git in this case). Adding to `lib` will work if you prefer it that way, but as I said the transitive dependencies may not be correct.